# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator Eigenvalues Confusion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

In standard PDE theory, one generates eigenvalues to Sturm-Liouville problems over a finite domain. So, for a wave equation, we have an infinite number of eigenvalues $_$ for a Dirichlet problem, say.

What is the mathematical justification for having an infinite number of energy eigenvalues for the quantum harmonic oscillator? The eigenfunctions are Hermite functions, but over the infinite domain, $-\infty < x < \infty$. Is there some existence theorem that guarantees this discrete set of eigenvalues even on an infinite domain?

Comment: The Physicist's justification comes from looking at the operators involved. There are so-called ladder operators that take an eigenfunction with one eigenvalue $\lambda$ to another with an eigenvalue $\lambda\pm\Delta\lambda$. It seems that these were introduced by Schrodinger, and they give a valid justification in Mathematics as well. I don't know of a more general justification, but there probably is one coming from a general Theorem of Math.

Comment: [This paper is concerned with the numerical solution of Schrodinger equations with 
so-called confinement potentials, that is, potentials tending to infinity at infinity.  ... 
It is well-known that such operators have a purely discrete, unbounded spectrum
consisting of eigenvalues of finite multiplicity.](http://www.math.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/i26/Bilder_Webseite/AG_ModNumDiff/FG_NumAnaPartDiff/Harry_Yserentant/gagelman-yserentant.pdf). They do not give a reference for "well-known".

Comment: [This paper](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/08/08-191.pdf?) (in the Introduction) calls it "One of the most celebrated elementary results on
Schrodinger operators".

Comment: [Introduction to Spectral Theory of Schr¨odinger Operators, p.72 ](http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/~amen/posters/pankov.pdf#page=74)